# two buttons call the same function

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have two buttons that would make different actions, but for some reason I can not, and just call the same function. It seems strange that happens, they are all tightly closed tags and I never had happened. Most likely it is my mistake, but I can not find it

For example, the first button calls the `getPhoto()` (function), this leaves some logs for the beginning of each function and thus identify which called.Effectively it works on the first button, unlike the second calls the function `getPicture()` but when to click, call "getPhoto"

```
             <label class="toggle toggle-assertive">
               <button class="button button-small button-orange" ng-click="getPhoto()">
                  Tomar imagen
               </button>
               <button class="button button-small button-orange" ng-click="getPicture()">
                Seleccionar imagen
              </button>
             </label>
```

Function :

```
$scope.getPicture = function(){
console.log("GET PICTURE");
var options = {
  quality: 50,
  destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
  popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
};

Camera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageURI) {

  $scope.lastPhoto = imageURI;

}, function(err) {
  // error
});
};

 $scope.getPhoto = function() {
  console.log("GET PHOTO");
var options = {
  quality: 50,
  destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  allowEdit: true,
  encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
  correctOrientation: true
};

Camera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageURI) {
  //console.log(imageURI);
  $scope.lastPhoto = imageURI;
}, function(err) {
  // error
});
};
```

Comment: Can you describe your issue bit more clearly? Which click does not work?

Comment: @PSL The click if it works, the problem is that in either clicks the same function is and does not respect the ng-click of another button.

Comment: Can you show us more code? Try updating this example with your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/14007/

Comment: @FacundoPedrazzini Edit your file and perform as it should, I do not know because my project does not work well.

Comment: Sioesi, your code appears okay (as far as `console.log` for each function is concerned). you may want to check if you're bootstrapping angular correctly..i.e. loading the script, calling the ng-app name correctly, declaring angular.module correctly, calling the right controller from the template etc.

Comment: I have got the same problem. Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the two buttons are inside the same label, just change it to a div or use two different labels